# How to read an xml that is in the form of an InputStream

Tags: java, xml, inputstream

In my web service i'm getting the xml i have to validate against a schema as an InputStream. 
I have to choose different schema files based if there is a "version" attribute in the root element of the xml.
Is there an inexpensive way of doing this or do i have to convert the InputStream to an XML and parse through it?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. InputStream isn't a 'form', it is a way of connecting to the data. You don't 'convert' InputStreams to XML, you just read them.

Comment: By 'validating against a schema as an InputStream', do you mean that you don't have opportunity to recreate the input stream, i.e. preparse, close the stream, and then reparse with the schema validator?

Answer (score 1):

Try [the tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) to get a grip on the basics of XML processing in Java. In particular, there are sections on validating XML while parsing with [SAX](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/validation.html) or [DOM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/validating.html). Note that there are also numerous other ways of parsing XML, like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html), [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/), and [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/), to name a few.